# onchange event in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to implement `onchange` event in jQuery on select field,as jQuery does not create cross browsers compatibility problems. My scripting code is:

```
<script>
  $('#payment_method').change(function () {
     if ($('#payment_method').val() == 'check') {
        alert('hello');
     }  
  });
</script>
```

and here is the code for the select field:

```
<select id="payment_method" name="country" class="form-control" >
    <option value="">Select One</option>
    <option value="check">Check</option>
    <option value="bank_transfer">Bank/Wire Transfer</option>
    <option value="paypal">Paypal</option>
    <option value="smart_card">Smart Money Card</option>
</select>
```

but nothing is happening when I select check option.

Comment: Your code is executing before the DOM is ready wrap your code in `$(document).ready(function(){});` or similar dom ready event.

Comment: No need for the 2nd $('#payment_method'), just use $(this) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need **ready event** to run your code when document is ready.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#payment_method').change(function () {
       if ($(this).val() == 'check') {
       alert('hello');
      } 
    });
      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be useful to use

```
$(this).val()
```

instead of

```
$('#payment_method').val()
```

to avoid DOM lookups.